# Why is "reject" not removing duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to remove duplicate entries based on my hash keys. What am I missing?

Here is the Hash:

```
  @ips_events += [timestamp: ips_timestamp,hostname: ips_hostname,signature_id: sig_id,signature_name: sig_name,
                 protocol: sig_protocol, attacker: ips_attacker_ip,attacker_port: ips_attacker_port,
                 target: ips_target,target_port: ips_target_port]
```

I'm trying to remove all duplicates based on the `[signature_id: sig_id, attacker: ips_attacker_ip, target: ips_target]` keys:

```
  @filtered_ips_events = @ips_events.reject { |k| k[signature_id: sig_id, attacker: ips_attacker_ip, target: ips_target] }
```

Comment: Enumeration.reject takes a block which it expects to yield a value `true` for records that are to be rejected.  Are you sure your code fragment within the block is executing correctly?  Blocks tend to swallow exception silently, which can lead to inexplicable behaviour.

Comment: No I'm not 100% sure my code is executing correctly.

Comment: wrap the contents of the block inside a rescue block and dump any exception it raises to STDERR.  It may be that you're falling foul of the silent exception issue.

Comment: The syntax `[a: 1, b: 2]` actually creates an _array_ with a _hash_ in it - `[{:a => 1, :b => 2}]`. Don't use this syntax, unless you absolutely know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reject doesn't have any context to know what is or isn't already in there to remove duplicates.

Using the `uniq` method, and provide what's unique about the row, for example:

```
@ips_events.uniq { |e| [e[:signature_id], e[:attacker], e[:ips_target]] }
```

Should get you where you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

What makes an event a duplicate? I'll assume same timestamp and signature here....please note that this may not be best choice for a large data set, but for a quick and dirty it gets the job done.

```
@filtered_ips_events = @ips_events.uniq{ |event| "#{event.timestamp} #{event.signature_id}" }
```

Basically, build a string that is "unique enough" for each event.